# Does workerpool declared in multiple routes can still maintain its cpu usage without caring about threshold

Tags: javascript, node.js, worker, worker-thread, worker-pool

I hope to figure out a node.js system with workerpool to handle cpu intensive tasks, but
there is something confused me about the cpu usage in multiple routes.
A scenario is like this:

```
route1.js:
  const workerpool = require('workerpool');
  const pool = workerpool.pool(__dirname + '/job1.js');
  pool.exec.......
route2.js:
  const workerpool = require('workerpool');
  const pool = workerpool.pool(__dirname + '/job2.js');
  pool.exec.......
route3.js:
  const workerpool = require('workerpool');
  const pool = workerpool.pool(__dirname + '/job3.js');
  pool.exec.......
```

When the node.js use these three files, they will create their own workerpool, and
since worker_thread number and its control is via node.js internals,  is this possible to
create threshold problem?  And how to use workerpool in a correct way, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is only have one pool of worker. Workers can expose multiple functions so your worker could expose job1, job2 and job3 without problem. If you create a pool for each, you'll need to consider that pools may work against each other...

Consider your pools getting 100% of your CPUs, that means you can require up to 300% what you have available if all 3 pools are full.

If you allocated them 33% each, that means you can require up to 100% which is good, but if only job1 is heavily required at one time it will only be able to use 33% of available resources.

By using a single pool, you can reach up to 100% without requiring more than 100% available.

Comment: There somehow has an api called pool.terminate(), if the threadpool theory is valid in workerpool, why there needs a pool.terminate to delete all the worker_thread? Will that clean the other workerpool I declared in other functions? If not, if there possible a dynamic and static workerpool can exist at the same time, thanks.

Comment: From what I understand it will terminate the pool, so only its worker_thread. I do not understand what you mean by dynamic and static workerpool. If you have a defined and precise use case, I suggest you explain it or else only generic/vague answers can be given.